# jQuery mobile 1.1.0 slider: JS-object properties access?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, slider

**EDIT:** This could be seen as a pure javascript objects question. The code can be found here:
[jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js)

I need to access properties of a jQuery mobile JS-object but is not sure how that is possible. In the jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js and mobile.slider is the following (see extend on line 5967):

```
$.widget( "mobile.slider", $.mobile.widget, {
  ...
  _create: function() {
    ...
    $.extend( this, {
      slider: slider,
      handle: handle,
      valuebg: valuebg,
      dragging: false,
      beforeStart: null,
      userModified: false,
      mouseMoved: false
    });
```

Primarily the property I would like to read is the "dragging".

I know i can execute the methods using:

```
$("#slider").slider("refresh")
```

Is there a similair way to access the properties?

Thanks

Comment: maybe a start but I can't access $.extend : http://jsfiddle.net/Gucsw/2/

Comment: A good start. But it seems to be accessing the "generic object", not the current existing slider JS-object. Ie the properties printed to console is not for the existing slider. (and as you said, still no access to the properties added with extend...)

Comment: Well this might be it: http://jsfiddle.net/Gucsw/7/

Comment: No, the "draggle" property seems like a setting for if the slider should be draggable or not(?). It does not change value when draggig the slider. I would have like a way to access the "dragging" variable without meddling with JQM, but instead I found I could do an extension of the object that solved my problem and will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**How to react to user dragging the slider, without having to bind mouse-/tap-events, but instead using the JQM functionallity already in place.**

To access the "dragging" variable of the JQM slider object I made an extension to the object as follows:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.slider.prototype.getDragging = function(){
    return this.dragging;
  };
});
```

With that in place, I can choose to react to changes only done by the user:

```
$("#slider").live('change',function(){
  if($("#slider").slider("getDragging"))){
    console.log('User is dragging slider to new value'); 
  }
  else {
    console.log('Program changed value. (or user typed in visible textbox)') ;
  }
});
```

With the slider textbox hidden, this give me the benefit of:

1. Using the "change"-event to react to user dragging without being triggered when my program change the slider value.
2. When my program is going to change the slider value, it can first check that the user is NOT currently dragging the slider.